# Failed to print PDF file with MPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

I want to export a report page into PDF file and I am using MPDF. I am following its tutorials step by step but I get blank page of PDF file. 
in controller :

```
function download(){
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    $this->load->model('mod');
    $data['result'] = $this->mod->getReport();
    $html = $this->load->view('Laporan/index', $data);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output('report.pdf', "D");    
}
```

What's wrong with it? Why it is pringting a blank pdf file?

Comment: `echo $html` and check. You will get an answer

Comment: It is showing not a blank page. But with all its content @Abdulla

Comment: can post it part of that

Comment: a part of what? my view page / $html? @Abdulla

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function download(){
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    $this->load->model('mod');
    $data['result'] = $this->mod->getReport();

    $html = $this->load->view('Laporan/index', $data, true);

    $mpdf = $this->m_pdf->load(); # added 

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); # Changed
    $mpdf->Output('report.pdf', "D");    # Changed
}
```

Check your library is loaded

```
if(class_exists('m_pdf')) {
    echo "loded";
}
else{
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdulla But it is not working, an error occur. 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method M_pdf::load()

Comment: are you sure library is loaded ??

Comment: @Diyah go through this [tutorial](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrate-mpdf-into-codeigniter-framework/)

Comment: how to check that my library is loaded?

Comment: Go through above link. they clearly show how to add and where to add

Comment: @Diyah i have added checking library load. try once

Comment: Yeah,. I try like a tutorial but it still printing a blank page

Comment: Change exist `$html` to this `$html = "test";`

Comment: It say Call to a member function WriteHTML() on null